# Time Series Analysis for Coordinates using LSTM

Tags: time-series, prediction, spatial, lstm, gis

I have a dataset in which ids of locations connected with corresponding latitudes and longtitudes. I want to predict  next location of the activity after training my LSTM model. However, feeding the ids as sequences directly to LSTM doesn't seem suitable since ids are not related with distances between locations. For example distance between id:1 and id:4 can be less than distance between id:1 and id:2.

One approach that comes to my mind is to cluster the locations according to their corresponding lat. and long. data. However output of this clustering is again new cluster ids.I am stuck at this point. Maybe one-hot encoding of cluster ids may work while feeding input for LSTM.

Any suggestions for solving this problem or any approach or recommendation for modelling this case will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Does each ID have a *time-series* of lat-long measurements? If so, you'd typically just feed a padded array to the LSTM of shape $n \times T \times d$ where $T$ is the max. length of a series and $d$ is the number of variables (sounds like you have 2: latitude & longitude). If they're not time-series, LSTM may not be the best approach.

Comment: There are many features of my dataset. One of them is location id. In other data sheet i have the corresponding lat.and long. of these location ids. I want to cluster these locations and feed them into my lstm network because spatial closeness is important feature for analyzing my dataset. And yes, my data is time series. Thank you in advance.